# Encrypted password

Tags: ssh

I need to transfer 3-4 files located on multiple servers to a central server.I currently do manual "scp" from these servers to copy files on central server.

Please suggest how can i do that automatically without it asking for password.I know i can do it by configuring "passwordless" authentication using "ssh-keygen" but this is not too secure and our organization is not approving the same.I have also use "sshpass" but "sshpass" is showing my password in a script which again is a security concern.

Please suggest how to provide encrypted password to "sshpass" whhich will solve my issue.

Comment: "*I know i can do it by configuring "passwordless" authentication using "ssh-keygen" but this is not too secure and our organization is not approving the same.*" **Your organisation is an idiot.**  It's a damn sight more secure than embedding a password - which will need to be in plaintext, or at least reversibly-encrypted which amounts to the same thing - in a script.

Answer (score 4):

For sshpass you can encrypt your password using gpg as described at the bottom of this article: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/

However, I'm going to echo @MadHatter's comment as an answer here: someone in your organisation needs to be educated about passwordless logins using keys. They are *not* insecure and are considerably more secure than any kind of passworded login.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment to reply to @MadHatter's comment:

Something that gets overlooked quite often, the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file  supports many options to place restrictions what a specific key is allowed.

Please check [`man 8 sshd`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd) for all options but often many of the perceived risks can be completely mitigated by restricting a specific (passwordless) ssh key pair:

- to perform only specific actions with **`command=`**
- allow only a specific set of remote hosts access with **`from="pattern-list"`**
- disable interactive login sessions with **`no-pty`**.

Comment: And even more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110939/48232

Comment: Thanks all for the reply!!!

 ssh keys are not recommended as anyone can spoof into server using username.

Also i have seen that link of sshpass.but that link was not useful as we can see password in a file while decryption.

Please let me know is there any method by which i can transfer files by giving encrypted password to "scp" command or something like that other than using "sshkeys"???.

Comment: Respectfully, whoever told you both of those things has no idea what they are talking about. Anyone can *attempt* to connect to a server with a username but without the correct private key the connection will be rejected. Also I don't believe that a pgp encrypted password is visible over an ssh connection if configured correctly because the connection itself is encrypted.